# Java FileDialog browse and read from file

Tags: java, user-interface, swt

I've a button to browse file/s with FileDialog. I need to read all lines from the file I've choose, I've tried a lot of things but nothing work to me :( I have another button that when I press on it, it will read the file and than print it.

```
        Button btnBrowse = new Button(composite_2, SWT.NONE);
    btnBrowse.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            FileDialog fileBrowse = new FileDialog(pmComp, SWT.MULTI);
            fileBrowse.setFilterExtensions(new String[] {"*.txt"});
            String filePath = fileBrowse.open();
            if (filePath != null) {
                StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
                files = fileBrowse.getFileNames();
                for (int i = 0, n = files.length; i < n; i++) {
                  buf.append(fileBrowse.getFilterPath());
                  if (buf.charAt(buf.length() - 1) != File.separatorChar) {
                    buf.append(File.separatorChar);
                  }
                  buf.append(files[i]);
                  buf.append("\n");
                }
                for (int i = 0, n = files.length; i < n; i++) {
                    listViewer.add(files[i]);
                }

                System.out.println(buf);

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you please share some more code? Also the snippet you have included seems to only list files.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking. This code just seems to build a list of selected files. You can read a text file's contents using `Files.readAllLines`.

Comment: yea, I want to create button that take each file from list and read all line and print it.

Comment: I dont know how to use the file I've choose as variable to use in another button.. thats all

Comment: Chosen where? The code you have shown us builds a list of files in something called `listViewer` - what is that?

Comment: The user Chose a file from PC, and the file added to lists,I dont know how to use the file and the file path from the list to read from this file only when I click anothe button "Start"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the sample code:

Here `btnBrowseFile` is button on which we need to select file

```
this.btnBrowseFile.addListener(SWT.Selection, event -> {
        final Shell shell = this.getShell();
        final FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog(shell, SWT.OPEN);
        dialog.setText("Select valid text file");
        dialog.setFilterExtensions("*.txt");
        String selectedFileStr = dialog.open();
        if (selectedFileStr != null && !selectedFileStr.isEmpty()) {
            final Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(selectedFileStr), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            List<String> readList = lines.collect(Collectors.toList());
            lines.close();
            readList.forEach(line -> {
                System.out.println(line);
                // Do your work
            });
        }
    });
```